# Optimize my page and zoom out issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to teach myself jquery and to do a decent layout.
I think what i have done is ok but i have questions. this is the first time ive attempted jquery from my own head and not copied someone elses.

Ive tried to keep it relevant and simple.

First question.
Ive used the optimizing tools in chrome and im having trouble with this
**Optimize the order of styles and scripts (1)
The following external CSS files were included after an external JavaScript file in the document head. To ensure CSS files are downloaded in parallel, always include external CSS before external JavaScript.
1 inline script block was found in the head between an external CSS file and another resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS file, or after the next resource.**
Every time i try this it breaks the pages css. Why and what should i be thinking about to solve this issue?

Second question:
Ive made a simple jquery slider under my menu... It does what i want it to but when i zoom out to 25% It doesnt stay in the wrapper, it shoot of to the side of the page. i have tried all weekend to solve this with no success. advice would be great, im stuck with this.

Over all im looking to see wheather im doin stuff as it should be.

Thrid:
When i zoom out the text on the page doesnt seem to shrink with the rest of the page.
***Is this normal?***

So here it is please pick holes in it..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bretts Gaming</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/superfish.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/colorbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">


<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="./css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/superfish2.css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/go.fullBg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#banner-rotate').cycle({
    fx:    'fade',
    speed:  500
    });
     $('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
     autoArrows:  false
     });
     $("#background_image").fullBg();
        var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2  ) ,
        slidecont = $('#menu-slide');
        slidecont.stop().animate({
        'left': left,
        });
    $('#navbar li').on('mouseover', function(){
            var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2 - 10) ,
            slidecont = $('#menu-slide'),
            navdiv = $('#slider-container').width()
            slidecont.stop().animate({
            'left': left,
            'position': 'absolute'
        });
    });
    $('#navbar li').on('mouseleave', function(){
        var left = $('.first').offset().left + ($('.first').width() / 2 - 10) ,
        slidecont = $('#menu-slide');
        slidecont.stop().animate({
        'left': left,
        });
    });
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:600, innerHeight:519});
    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
                $("#click").click(function(){ 
                    $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                    return false;
                });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background_image"><img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/bg.png" width="1679" height="939"/></div>
<div id="background_overlay">
    <div id="site">
        <div id="header_wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo"><img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/logo.png" width="366" height="41"/></div>
                    <div id="topnav">
                        <ul id="navbar"class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="current first"><a href="#a">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">CORPORATE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CRUSING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LEISURE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">GROUPS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">VIRTUOSO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="slider-container">
                            <div id="menu-slide"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="body_wrapper">
            <div id="body">
                <div id="home_sec_1">
                    <div id="banner_left">
        <div id="banner-rotate" class="pics">
            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/banner1.png" width="493" height="199" />
            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/banner2.png" width="493" height="199" />
            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/banner3.png" width="493" height="199" />
            </div>
        </div>
                    <div id="banner_right">
                        <div class="avert adFirst">
                            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/smallimg1.png" width="66" height="59"/>
                            <h2>DIRT 3</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit.</p>
                            <div class="checklinks"><a href="index.html">Check It Out.</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="avert">
                            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/smallimg2.png" width="66" height="59" />
                            <h2>DEAD ISLAND</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit.</p>
                            <div class="checklinks"><a href="index.html">Check It Out.</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="avert adLast">
                            <img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/smallimg3.png" width="66" height="59"/>
                            <h2>CALL OF DUTY: MW3</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit.</p>
                            <div class="checklinks"><a href="index.html">Check It Out.</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="home_sec_2">
                    <h2>WHATS IN THE MIX</h2>
                    <div class="home_sec_2_img home_sec_2_img_1" >
                        <a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bdjnbWXKsOA?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" title="A Weird Fuckin Game"><img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/midimg1.png" width="314" height="145"/></a>                     
                        <p>LA NORIE</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="home_sec_2_img">                        
                        <a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TfrrAp1blaM?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" title="Battlefield 3 Goin Off"><img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/midimg2.png" width="314" height="145"/></a>
                        <p>BATTLEFIELD 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="home_sec_2_img">
                        <a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C4nMEoYIchU?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" title="Call Of Duty MW3"><img src="images/pictures/large/system-files/midimg3.png" width="314" height="145"/></a>
                        <p>CALL OF DUTY: MW3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="home_sec_3">
                <div class="liist-one">
                    <ul id="lst1" class="sujest">
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="liist-one">
                    <ul id="lst3" class="sujest">
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="liist-one">
                    <ul id="lst3" class="sujest">
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec  tetuer adi eat.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
            <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
            <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p>

            <p><strong>If you try to open a new ColorBox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
            <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
            <a class="ajax" href="../content/flash.html">Click here to load new content</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<div id="footer_wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_left">© 2012 Bretts Gaming&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Web Design Gold Coast&nbsp;-&nbsp;Bretts Web Pages</a></div>
        <div id="footer_right"><a href="#">Sitemap</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Bookmark this Site</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And the css**

```
html,body { margin:0px; padding:0px; height:100%; }
body, td { font-family: arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; color:#ffffff;}

body { background:#ffffff; }


/* links */
a, a:visited { color: #f67c38; text-decoration:underline; } 
a:hover { color: #f67c38; text-decoration:underline; } 
p { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
h1, .heading, .redheading { color:#eca007; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:0px 0px 15px 0px; }
h2, .subheading, .sitemaphdrdiv { color:#e16a15; font-size:15px; line-height:18px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:5px 0px; }
/** template styles */
#background_image { overflow:hidden;}
#background_overlay {position: absolute;  top: 0;  left: 0;  z-index: 50;  width: 100%;  height:100%;  overflow-y:auto; } 
#background_overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 50; width: 100%; height:100%;  overflow-y:auto; background-attachment: fixed; }
#wrapper-blank-template { background: #000000; height:100%; }
#main-blank-template { padding: 14px 20px; }
#site { min-height:100%;  }
#header_wrapper { height:157px; }
#header { margin:0px auto; width:980px; height:157px; padding: 0px;}
#logo { margin:16px 0px 8px 0px; width:498px;  height: 120px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/logobg.png) no-repeat;}
#logo img{ padding:32px 0px 0px 61px; }
#topnav { width: 980px; height: 39px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/navbg.png) no-repeat; }
#navbar {position: relative; width: 980px; height: 29px;  }
#navbar a { text-decoration:none;}
#navbar ul{text-align: center;}
#menu-slide {height: 4px; width: 52px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/glowbg.png) no-repeat;  position: absolute; float: left; } 
#header_right { float:right; display:inline; width:311px; font-size:19px; line-height:36px; font-weight:bold; color:#1f1104; text-align:center; padding: 12px 0px 12px 0px;  }
#body_wrapper { padding-bottom:90px; } /* padding bottom matches height of the footer + padding */
#body { margin:0px auto; width:980px; }
#home_sec_1 {height: 216px; width: 980px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/section1.png) no-repeat center top; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; display:inline-block;}
#banner_left {width: 493px; height: 199px; margin: 9px 0px 9px 15px; float: left; display:inline-block;}
#banner_right {width: 453px; height: 199px; margin: 9px 0px 5px 5px; float: left; display:inline-block; }
.avert {height: 65px; width: 448px; padding-top: 0px; border-bottom: dashed 1px; border-spacing: 3px; border-bottom-color: #635c54; position: relative;}
.checklinks {float: right; bottom: 35px; position: absolute; float: right; bottom: 2px; right: 0px; }
.checklinks a{text-decoration: none;}
.avert img{ float:left; padding-right: 10px;}
.avert h2{ padding: 3px;}
.adfirst{padding-top: 0px;}
.adlast{border-bottom: 0px;}
#home_sec_2 {height: 216px; width: 980px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/section2.png) no-repeat center top; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 5px; text-decoration: none;}
#home_sec_2 h2 { padding-left: 12px;}
#home_sec_2 p { padding-top: 0px;} 
.home_sec_2_img{ padding:3px;float: left; }
.home_sec_2_img_1{ padding-left: 12px;}
#home_sec_3 { height: 216px; width: 980px; background: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/section3.png) no-repeat center top; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; }
#home_sec_3 a, a:hover{text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff}
.liist-one{width: 315px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px;}
.liist-one ul{list-style-image: url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/bullet.png); line-height: 30px;font-size: 12px;}
#content_bg { margin-top:7px;  background:#000000 url(../images/pictures/large/system-files/bg_content.gif) repeat-y; }
#content_left { float:left; display:inline; padding:20px 0px; margin-left:20px; width:629px;}
#content_right { float:right; display:inline; padding:25px 0px; margin-right:25px; width:261px; }
#content_right h1 { color:#ffffff; margin:3px 0px 20px 0px; }
#content_right a, #content_right a:visited { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; }
#content_right a:hover { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; }
#footer_wrapper { position:fixed; bottom:0px; height:37px; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 0%, rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 1%, rgba(6,6,6,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54)), color-stop(1%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54)), color-stop(100%,rgba(6,6,6,1))); /* chrome,safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 0%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 1%,rgba(6,6,6,1) 100%); /* chrome10+,safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 0%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 1%,rgba(6,6,6,1) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 0%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 1%,rgba(6,6,6,1) 100%); /* ie10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 0%,rgba(42,42,42,0.54) 1%,rgba(6,6,6,1) 100%); /* w3c */
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient( startcolorstr='#8a2a2a2a', endcolorstr='#060606',gradienttype=0 ); /* ie6-9 */
width:100%; color:#ffffff; } /* padding bottom matches height of the footer + padding */
#footer { margin:0px auto; width:980px; font-family:verdana; font-size:10px; line-height:40px; color:#ffffff; }
#footer_left { float:left; }
#footer_right { float:right; padding-right: 5px; }
#footer a, #footer a:visited { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; }
#footer a:hover { color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline; }
```

Im not sure how to put all the scripts here, how do i do this so you guys can see the page?
Hope this is right..
*Im a complete beginner so if im doing this incorrectly please tell me*
Oh yes!
When I click the links on the page the slider shoots to the side of the page for a second then goes to the correct place, again very stuck

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Include items in your head in the following order:

1. meta for encoding
2. `<title>` tag
3. other meta tags
4. Inline `<script>` or `<style>` tags
5. reference(s) to CSS files
6. reference(s) to JS files

an exception to this is that IE-specific CSS needs to be placed *after* all other CSS

Question 2 and 3:
Some browser start acting weird when you change the zoom of the page if all sizes are not defined in the CSS. for example, `.checklinks` in your css.

Other:

1. CSS should not have a `;` after the last property
2. Make a JS file instead of having it inline in the head. Also combine scripts as possible, except *always* keep jQuery and other libraries separate.